# $\dim(\ker L^*) = \dim(\operatorname{coker} L)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

> Let $L:D \rightarrow H$ be a [closed](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/), self adjoint operator, with two additional properties: 
>   (a) closed image.
>   (b) finite dimensional kernel.
>
> Is it true that $\dim(\ker L^*) = \dim (\operatorname{coker} L)$?

---

The reason I asked this is because when $D=H$, and $L$ is in fact bounded the result is true. What I have is written below.

---

If $L$ were a bounded self adjoint operator with $D=H$, then $H= \operatorname{im}(L) \oplus \operatorname{im} (L)^\perp =\operatorname{im}(L) \oplus \ker(L^*)$

(I) $\ker (L^*) \subseteq \operatorname{im} (L)^\perp$

(II) If $x \in \operatorname{im} L^\perp \cap \ker L$, 
$$ \langle x , Ly \rangle = 0 \Rightarrow \langle L^*x,y \rangle = 0$$

for all $y \in D$, hence $x \in \ker L^*$.

---

So we may write $H \supseteq \ker(L^*) \oplus \operatorname{im}(L)$ a dense subset of $H$.

Comment: Is $H$ a hilbert space and $D$ a subspace? Is $D$ closed?

Comment: $H$ is a Hilbert space, $D$ is a dense subspace.  The definition of closed is as link in the notes by Tao.